# Windows registry textual format?

Tags: windows, registry, file-format

`regedit.exe` and `reg.exe` are able to "export" and "import" files in a human readable textual format. Is there a public API or some library which can read this format I can use programatically?
Even just converting this format to a hive file format would be enough.
I'm looking for a way to take such files and do a `RegLoadKey()` on them

Comment: Those programs do not process hives. The just call the regular registry APIs like RegSetValueEx. You can see another example in the rgs parser that comes with ATL. That ships as source code so you can use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, .reg file format could be parsed with any .ini file parser. Although, the tree structure maintenance has to be given some extra.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> ..., it doesn't use the textual .REG
>   format, because parsing that is as much trouble as parsing the
>   original binary format. Instead it makes the file available through a
>   C API, and then wraps this API in higher level scripting and GUI
>   tools.

[hivex - Windows Registry "hive" extraction library](http://libguestfs.org/hivex.3.html)